# Graph function with exponential y-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I need to graph a function with 2 constants (\varepsilon and \k) and 1 variable (\m). I use `\declarefunction`.

My problem is that que y-axis are too small and I don't know how to set them in my code to have the output that I expect.
The function is this:

```
\[
f(m,\varepsilon,k)=\frac{\left( 1-\varepsilon \right) }{2}\left( 1-\left(
1-\varepsilon \right) ^{m}-m\left( 1-\varepsilon \right) ^{m-1}\varepsilon
\right) +\frac{\varepsilon }{2}\left( 2-(1-k\varepsilon )^{m}\right) -\frac{m%
}{2}\varepsilon (1-k\varepsilon )^{m-1}k\varepsilon \left( 1+\frac{\left(
1-\varepsilon \right) \left( 1-\varepsilon \right) ^{m-1}\varepsilon }{%
\left( 1-\varepsilon \right) \varepsilon +\varepsilon (1-k\varepsilon )^{m}}%
\right) 
\]
```

Then, my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
     every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={b},
            ylabel={r},
            axis lines=left,
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci e},
            declare function={f(\m,\e,\k)=
            ((1-\e)/(2))*
            (1-pow((1-\e),\m)-\m*\e*(pow((1-\e),(\m-1))))+
            (\e/2)*(2-pow((1-\k*\e),\m))-
            (\m/2)*\e*\k*\e*pow((1-\k*\e),(\m-1))*
            (1+(((1+\e)*pow((1-\e),(\m-1))*\e)/((1-\e)*\e+\e*(pow(1-\k*\e),\m))))
            ;},
            domain=1:8,no marks,samples=20
            ,smooth, ymin=0.00044, ymax=0.000445, xmin=2, xmax=5,
            extra x ticks={2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75},
            extra x tick labels={ },
%            extra y ticks={1.425, 1.435, 1.445, 1.455},
%            extra y tick labels={ },
            tick label style={font=\scriptsize}]
\addplot[color=black, domain=2:5, variable = \m]{f(m, 0.001, 100)};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The expected output is the following one.

[image]

Could any one help me to set that y-axis values to obtain that graph ?
I've tried some values but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT: Implementation in `gnuplot`

Plotting the same function with `gnuplot` results in the desired output, which differs from the `pgfplots` one, see **original answer**.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
    every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
        xlabel={b},
        ylabel={r},
        axis lines=left,
        scaled ticks=false,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=3,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            sci,sci e,
            /tikz/.cd,},
        xmin=2, xmax=5,
        ymin=0.000441, ymax=0.000456,
        extra x ticks={2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75},
        extra x tick labels={ },
        ytick={0.000441,0.000443,...,0.000456},
        ]
      \addplot[color=red, samples=20, smooth,domain = 2:5, no markers] gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{ %
        f(x)=((1-eps)/2)*(1-(1-eps)**x-x*(1-eps)**(x-1)*eps)+eps/2*(2-(1-k*eps)**x)-x/2*eps*k*eps*(1-k*eps)**(x-1)*(1+((1+eps)*(1-eps)**(x-1)*eps)/((1-eps)*eps+eps*(1-k*eps)**x));
        eps=0.001;k=100;
        plot[x=2:5] f(x);
         };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Original answer

My output to your function differs a little bit to your expected one (maybe I have missed something!?):
[image]

The `declare function` has to be implemented in the `tikzpicture` environment and not in the `axis` definition. You have also forgotten a bracket, see last `pow((1-\k*\e,\m)`. Furthermore, after changing directory to the `number format` of `yticklabel style` you have to change back to the tikz one.

With the y-axis limits `ymin=0.00044` and `ymax=0.00045`

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},
    every non boxed y axis/.append style={y axis line style=-}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
         declare function={f(\m,\e,\k)=
                    ((1-\e)/(2))*
                    (1-pow((1-\e),\m)-\m*\e*(pow((1-\e),(\m-1))))+
                    (\e/2)*(2-pow((1-\k*\e),\m))-
                    (\m/2)*\e*\k*\e*pow((1-\k*\e),(\m-1))*
                    (1+(((1+\e)*pow((1-\e),(\m-1))*\e)/((1-\e)*\e+\e*(pow((1-\k*\e),\m)))) % <-- bracket
                    ;},
        ]
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={b},
        ylabel={r},
        axis lines=left,
        scaled ticks=false,
        yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision=1,
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            sci,sci e,
            /tikz/.cd,}, %<-- change back to tikz directory
%       domain=1:8,
%       no marks,
        samples=20,
        smooth, 
%       ymin=0.00044, ymax=0.00045, 
        xmin=2, xmax=5,
        extra x ticks={2.25, 2.75, 3.25, 3.75, 4.25, 4.75},
        extra x tick labels={ },
        %            extra y ticks={1.425, 1.435, 1.445, 1.455},
        %            extra y tick labels={ },
        ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize}]
        \addplot[color=red, domain=2:5, variable = \m]{f(m, 0.001, 100)};
        \end{axis} 
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Edit: about the function and `pgfplots`

For comparison, I have plotted the function:

`((1-eps)/2)*(1-(1-eps)^x-x*(1-eps)^(x-1)*eps)+eps/2*(2-(1-k*eps)^x)-x/2*eps*k*eps*(1-k*eps)^(x-1)*(1+((1+eps)*(1-eps)^(x-1)*eps)/((1-eps)*eps+eps*(1-k*eps)^x))`

with `OriginLab`:
[image]

Now it is clear that the difference comes from `pgfplots` and how it computes the function. It seems to me that it has to do with the power.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer Ñako! I think that the differences between your output and the expected one (I really need to obtain that especific graph D:) is the values from the y-axis. In the expected one it goes from 4.4e-4 to 4.5e-4 and the actual is from 3.6e-4 to 4.4e-4. How could I modify that? Could you help me please? I check again the \declarefunction and that seems to be ok. Thanks :)

Comment: @TonyDis       Have a look at the edit and the answer of how to set the y-axis limits, please. I would recommend you to ask a new question about your function and `pgfplots`

Answer (score 3):

For fun and exercise: small off-topic variation of nice  [@Ñako](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560340/graph-function-with-exponential-y-axis/560373#560373) answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
             sci,
             sci generic={mantissa sep={\,},exponent={\textsc{e}^{#1}}},
             precision=1
            }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={f(\m,\e,\k)=
    ((1-\e)/2)*(1-pow((1-\e),\m)-\m*\e*(pow((1-\e),(\m-1))))+
    (\e/2)*(2-pow((1-\k*\e),\m))-
    (\m/2)*\e*\k*\e*pow((1-\k*\e),(\m-1))*(1+(((1+\e)*pow((1-\e),(\m-1))*\e)/((1-\e)*\e) +
    \e*(pow((1-\k*\e),\m)))));}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel={$b$},
    ylabel={$r$},
        x label style={at={(1,0)}, anchor=north east},
        y label style={at={(0,1)}, rotate=-90, anchor=north east},
scaled ticks=false,
    minor tick num=1,
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill}, 
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/sci},
    xmax=5.4, 
    domain=2:5, 
    samples=401, no marks
            ]
\addplot +[thick, variable=\m]{f(m, 0.001, 100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]